# Intermediate Result?

Tags: word-request

I'm trying to translate the Czech word *mezivýsledek* - the result of a part of calculation used to come up with the final result. E.g. gcd is an *(unknown word)* in the calculation of lcm, since lcm(a,b) = |a*b|/gcd(a,b).

According to my dictionary, the expression I'm looking for is *intermediate result*, but I failed to find any usage. Should I use *intermediate result*, or is there a more suitable term?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Intermediate result" is completely correct - I use that in my programming job all the time.

Another idiom is "interim result" - but that's more for when the final result will be delayed for quite a while: many days or weeks.

> "The interim result explains our optimistic forecast. But of course we won't really know until the final result!"